# How to convert a hexadecimal string of data to an ArrayBuffer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hex, arraybuffer

How do I convert the string `'AA5504B10000B5'` to an `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use regular expressions together with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
var hex = 'AA5504B10000B5'

var typedArray = new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
  return parseInt(h, 16)
}))

console.log(typedArray)
console.log([0xAA, 0x55, 0x04, 0xB1, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB5])

var buffer = typedArray.buffer
```

Answer (score 7):

Compact one-liner version:

```
new Uint8Array('AA5504B10000B5'.match(/../g).map(h=>parseInt(h,16))).buffer
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer throws an exception when the hex string is empty. Here is a safer solution:

```
function hex_decode(string) {
    let bytes = [];
    string.replace(/../g, function (pair) {
        bytes.push(parseInt(pair, 16));
    });
    return new Uint8Array(bytes).buffer;
}
```