# how to decrypt sha-256 encrypted text cloudflare workers

Tags: node.js, cloudflare-workers

I want to decrypt encrypted string, but when try to decrypt it using Textdecoder it return error. . Here is the error  `TypeError: Failed to execute 'decode' on 'TextDecoder': parameter 1 is not of type 'Array'.`

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
async function handleRequest(request) {
  const message = "81706cd5bd5049fc200560d3c9efada6418358e09bc135d3de4fa91817fb4768";
  const msgUint8 = new TextDecoder().decode(message)
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgUint8) 
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)) 
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => b.toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('') 
  return new Response(hashHex, {status: 200})
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131242/how-to-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-of-data-to-an-arraybuffer-in-javascript

Comment: How on earth are you "decrypting" a digest?