# Wrong result with HMAC verification using SubtleCrypto in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cryptography, shopify, hmac, subtlecrypto

I am trying to verify a HMAC signature using the SubtleCrypto API. The whole thing is supposed to run in Cloudflare Workers and I am testing it locally using their `wrangler` tool.

This is my code so far, but it generates the wrong signature.

```js
const message = "(query params from an url)";
const given_signature = "(extracted from the query params)";
const SECRET = "...";

const algorithm = { name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256' };
const encoder = new TextEncoder();

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    encoder.encode(SECRET),
    algorithm,
    false,
    ['sign', 'verify']
);

const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
    algorithm.name,
    key,
    encoder.encode(message)
);

const digest = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(signature)));
// The digest does not match the signature extracted from the query params

// If I, for example, want to verify the signature directly, the result is still false.
const verify = await crypto.subtle.verify(
    algorithm.name,
    key,
    encoder.encode(given_signature),
    encoder.encode(message)
);
```

**If I am using the same secret and message in online HMAC testing tools, I am getting the correct results, so I am certain that there must be a bug in my code.**

What I find interesting, is that the signature generated by my code is much shorter than the given one (e.g. `3fn0mhrebHTJMhtOyvRP5nZIhogX/M1OKQ5GojniZTM=` vs `ddf9f49a1ade6c74c9321b4ecaf44fe67648868817fccd4e290e46a239e26533`).

Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: it's simply different encoding, your signature (`3fn...ZTM=`) is base64 encoded, the other one is hex encoded. You can check on https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex and see that the values itself is identical when you convert base64 to hex.

Comment: the bottom one is encoded as HEX, the 1st is not - maybe thats a problem?

Comment: Ahhh yes, you both are correct, @jps and @Seti. How could I miss that? But I still wonder, why the `crypto.subtle.verify` function returned false. In any case, I can move on with my day, thank you!

Comment: Verification fails because `TextEncoder` UTF-8 encodes the hex encoded signature. However, it must be hex decoded, i.e. apply [`hex2buf(given_signature)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43131635/9014097) instead of `encoder.encode(given_signature)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments! The problem in a nutshell was that the provided signature was encoded as a HEX string, while the generated signature was a base64-encoded string.

To keep things clean, here is a working version that uses the `crypto.subtle.verify` function:

```js
const message = "(query params from an url w/o the hmac signature)";
const given_signature = "(the given hmac signature extracted from the query params)";
const SECRET = "(my secret key)";

const hexToBuffer = (hex: string) => {
  const matches = hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi) ?? [];
  const typedArray = new Uint8Array(
    matches.map(function (h) {
      return parseInt(h, 16);
    })
  );
  return typedArray.buffer;
};

const algorithm = { name: "HMAC", hash: "SHA-256" };
const encoder = new TextEncoder();

const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  encoder.encode(SECRET),
  algorithm,
  false,
  ["sign", "verify"]
);

const result: boolean = await crypto.subtle.verify(
  algorithm.name,
  key,
  hexToBuffer(given_signature),
  encoder.encode(message)
);
```